# What is the point of "community" bumping posts?

Tags: discussion, bump

Why is the "community" bot pulling up poor questions from 12/20/2012?

[onclick="location.href (etc)" on div doesnt wordk on IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974961/onclick-location-href-etc-on-div-doesnt-wordk-on-ie9)

First we really do not deal with IE9 any more, second it is 7 years old. Question should have been closed back then because it was a mistake on OPs part.

Comment: Well, it got the question closed so I guess the system sort of works?

Answer (score 3):

The banner tries to flesh out the reason:

> bumped to the homepage by Community♦ 13 mins ago
>
> This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed.

We get so much activity it's hard to see some posts that should be cleaned up but aren't.  Bumping to the front page gives passers-by another look to moderate the question if needs be.

Comment: Problem is with JavaScript a lot of 7+ year posts are so outdated and really useless. Yeah could be cleaned up, but most of the stuff in it is useless. Probably not right to delete it.